# Disable all post changes

Tags: google-plus

Am I able to disable new changes for a G+ post?

Say I post an image on G+ and somebody writes a really bad comment. I want to "conserve" the comment (disable new changes like deletion or editing of the respective comment) so I can show it to someone.

Comment: I don't see how. The person who wrote the comment "owns" it and will be able to edit or delete it. You can probably only take a screen shot. Better would be to report is as abuse.

Comment: Can you please answer by Answer to i can vote it or mark as an answer

Comment: it's not much of an answer, but okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how. The person who wrote the comment "owns" it and will be able to edit or delete it. You can probably only take a screen shot. Better would be to report it as abuse.